# Criar um Spinner a partir de uma lista fixa com mais de 1 campo

Tags: java, android

**Como faço para adicionar os valores nesse Spinner ?**

Preciso criar um `Spinner` que contenha 2 "campos" (cod, opcao).

Serão adicionados valores padrões, mas que posteriormente não podem ser alterados os códigos, então preciso do campo `cod` para quando adicionar outros valores, não terei problemas.

Para isso um `ArrayList` utilizando uma classe específica:

```
public class ArrayPadrao {

    private int id;
    private int cod;
    private String opcao;

    public ArrayPadrao(int cod, String opcao) {

        this.id = cod;
        this.opcao = opcao;
    }

    public int getCod() {
        return cod;
    }

    public String opcao() {
        return opcao;
    }

    //O que este método retornar é o que Spinner mostrará.
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return opcao;
    }
}
```

Tentei de algumas formas mas sem sucesso:

```
ArrayList<ArrayPadrao> lista = new ArrayList<>();
        lista.add(1, "aaa");
```

Vi algumas opções diferentes (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13738441/how-to-initialize-a-two-column-arraylist) com `List<>` e `Map + HashMap` mas gostaria de opiniões de qual a melhor forma para isso.

> **Código funcionando:**

```
public void spinnerTipo() {

        ArrayList<ArrayPadrao> lista = new ArrayList<>();
        lista.add(new ArrayPadrao(1, "aaa"));
        lista.add(new ArrayPadrao(2, "bbb"));
        lista.add(new ArrayPadrao(3, "ccc"));

        ArrayList<ArrayPadrao> tipos = lista;
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, tipos);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spnTipo.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Comment: Não está claro o que quer perguntar. Qual o problema com `lista.add(1, "aaa");`?

Comment: Ele não aceita. Diz que só pode 1 argumento. Acho que mesmo tendo a classe específica, ele não aceita... acho que teria que criar 1 obj para cada inserção.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem de primeiro criar uma instância de ArrayPadrao e adicioná-la ao ArrayList assim:

```
ArrayList<ArrayPadrao> lista = new ArrayList<>();
lista.add(new ArrayPadrao(1, "aaa"));
```

Comment: Matou ! Valeu pela ajuda do dia ! rs Abraço !